# How to add a new column in an existing table in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add a new column in one of my table in Rails 5. I recently renamed a column by using the following way:

```
rails g migration ChangeJobsTable
```

then in `20160802104312_change_jobs_table.rb`:

```
class ChangeJobsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_column :jobs, :skills, :skills1
  end
end
```

then

```
rails db:migrate
```

It worked fine, but now if I want to also add a new column `skills2`, do I need to do it like this?

```
class ChangeJobsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :jobs, :skills2
  end
end
```

Comment: you are on right track....go ahead

Comment: i got this error: rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3..4)

Comment: yes, just follow hgsongra(hitesh) instruction..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot to add `datatype`, below is the updated migration.

```
class ChangeJobsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :jobs, :skills2, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 18):

You indeed forgot the `datatype`. You can also do it via the console in the future:

`rails g migration AddSkills2ToJobs skills2:string`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and you can verify after in the schema

`rails g migration add_skills2_to_ChangeJobsTable skills2:string`

`rake db:migrate`